# change color of a specific column in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am attempting to customize the color of default [Datatables](https://datatables.net/). I managed to change the color of the header as i desire and the font but I am not change color of each column. For instance I have column that reports total deaths and I want it to be red. At the same time i want to make sure my header color stays fixed.

MY HTML CODE

```
<table id="myTable"></table>
    <div id="loadingLabel">Loading...</div
```

JS CODE

```
const getNewCases = async() => {
  const response = await fetch('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily/3-18-2020');
  const data = await response.json();
  let usa = data.filter(val => {
    return val.countryRegion === 'US';
  });
  $('#loadingLabel').hide();
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    data: usa,
    bLengthChange: false,
    bPaginate: false,
    scrollY:        '50vh',
    columns: [
      { data: 'provinceState', title: 'State' },
      { data: 'countryRegion', title: 'Country' },
      { data: 'lastUpdate', title: 'Last Update' },
      { data: 'confirmed', title: 'Confirmed' },
      { data: 'deaths', title: 'Deaths' },
      { data: 'recovered', title: 'Recovered' }
    ]
  });
};
getNewCases();
```

CSS Code

```
thead {
  background-color: #2c3e4f;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: wheat;
}
```

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4qa3502L/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use css nth-of-type

```
#myTable td:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Both answers are correct but accepting this one because if i had multiple tables i would have to insert the id as shown by this answer.

Comment: @Dinero I think the same thing, having to redo your code because it lacked precision at the start is a real plague

Answer (score 1):

You can change color of particular column using nth-child

```
    tr td:nth-child(5) {
        background: red;
    }
```